# Is my colleague happy with me?

Tags: steganography

So I graduated last year with a chemical degree and I started working in a lab. I'm still pretty nervous about making mistakes, so when I had to prepare a tricky experimental setup, I wrote down what I wanted to do and sent it to a colleague for him to check.
He's just a bit older than me, but seems much more confident. I can't really tell what he thinks of me, and the tone of his answer is not helping (copied it below). *Do you think he's happy with me?*

> Not sure about that formula (You can simplify the *solubility = that
>   complicated expression* line. 
>   In your case that expression is basically something $\times$ zero).
>   For your experimental part. I would  have used 10^2
>   instead of 10^1 mg of zinc but ok.
>   One thing though: ensure quantity of water - quantity of potassium > quantity of iodine.
>   Otherwise there is no point.

---

Hint 1

> Only very specific parts of the text are useful for this riddle.

Hint 2

> The text layout is important. Not sure this works on a phone screen. Edited the layout to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: Note 1 : I (writter of this puzzle) am not an actual chemist. So no <knowledge> tag, and if a real chemist reads this, please forgive this surely obviously-not-something-a-chemist-would-write paragraph

Comment: Note 2 : If this question fails to fly here, I think I can move it verbatim to the Workspace for it to thrive

Comment: Is the inclusion of the things that aren't chemicals here intentional (e.g. soda and iode)?

Comment: Nah, that's just me being and a non-native speaker who relied a bit too much on linguee. I'll edit it to make it a bit more realistic.

Comment: Modified it a bit. This confirms, if anyone was still wondering, that this has little to do with chemistry (don't start looking up for clues in Mendeleev's table..)

Comment: Alright so nothing to do with N2O2 (obtained by taking first capital letters) being **hyponitrite**, which you could possibly turn into **hypocrite** using other clues?

Comment: Nice one @Arnaud, but no, there is nothing chemistry-related !

Comment: Been a while, maybe some clues?

Comment: Yeah, any hints?